# Tiny numerical difference in sum-of-squares depending on numpy procedure call used

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point-precision, numerical

I am writing a function which computes sum of squares of errors. `x` and `y` are vectors of the same length; `y` is observation data, `x` is data computed by my model.

The code is like:

```
>> res = y.ravel() - x.ravel()
>> np.dot(res.T, res)
>> 1026.7059479504269

>> np.sum(res**2)
>> 1026.7059479504273
```

Now look at the last two digits. Can anyone tell me what is the reason for it? Both calls should result in the same operations. Does anyone know where this difference comes from?

Comment: I just can guess it is about rounding values. So nothing to worry.

Comment: Probably: http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3001761

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say it's how the `.dot` function works, which, while has the same result, would calculate the dot product on the fly, rather than  square all the numbers first, and then add them together. While it's pretty inconsequential for the numbers you are dealing with, I'd wager that `.dot` is more accurate than `np.sum(res**2)`

Comment: I wonder if `np.sum()` is doing a running-sum, and `np.dot` isn't. You can experiment by changing the order of res (e.g. sort it from low to high for maximum accuracy).  Anyway this is only at the 15th significant digit.

Comment: FYI: `res` is a 1D array, so there is no point in transposing it.   The "transpose" of a 1D numpy array is itself.  You can simply write `np.dot(res, res)`.

Comment: I not too sure that '.dot' is more accurate, '.dot' is a BLAS-call and most of the time optimized for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point addition is not associative--the order in which the operations are performed can affect the result.  Presumably `np.dot(res, res)` and `np.sum(res**2)` perform the operations in different orders.

Here's an example where `np.sum(x**2) != np.sum(x[:50]**2) + np.sum(x[50:]**2)` (and neither equals `np.dot(x, x)`):

```
>>> np.random.seed(1234)
>>> x = np.random.randn(100)
>>> np.sum(x**2)
99.262119361371433
>>> np.sum(x[:50]**2) + np.sum(x[50:]**2)
99.262119361371461
>>> np.dot(x, x)
99.262119361371447
```